# for loop inside a c function called by python causes termination without error message

Tags: python, c, loops, for-loop

I have a python code that calls c functions and is having a weird problem that terminates without any error message on the python command line.

I used the python pdb debug tool and find the program stops inside a c function, and I was able to precisely locate where the 'crash' happened. The part where the program stops is posted below. And I put some printf there for debugging.

```
      .
      .
      .
      printf("can u get here? \n");
     // Extract the mask from the final set of messages...
      targ = self->pixel;
      printf("%d \n", self->height);
      printf("%d \n", self->width);
      for (y=0;y<self->height;y++)
      {
       printf("y iteration starts \n");
       for (x=0;x<self->width;x++)
       {
           val = targ->bgCost;
        for (d=0;d<4;d++) val += targ->in[d];
        *m = (unsigned char*)(mask->data + y*mask->strides[0] + x*mask->strides[1]);
        if (val<0.0) *m = 1;
                else *m = 0;
        ++targ;
        printf("y is %d \n", y);
        printf("x is %d \n", x);
       }
      }
      .
      .
      .
```

When I run my python script on python command I got the following printf messages:

```
can u get here?
286
352
y iteration starts
y is 0, x is 0
y is 0, x is 1
y is 0, x is 2
y is 0, x is 3
y is 0, x is 4
y is 0, x is 5
y is 0, x is 6
y is 0, x is 7
        .
        .
        .

y is 0, x is 345
y is 0, x is 346
y is 0, x is 347
y is 0, x is 348
y is 0, x is 349
y is 0, x is 350
y is 0, x is 351
```

Based on my understanding, the code stops right after the inner x loop is finished and didn't start the second iteration of the outer y loop. (The bound for y and x are separately 286 and 352, and the code stops when y=0 and x=351)

I have no clue what could be causing this...

Comment: the proper tool here is the `gdb` debugger, not python debugger: attach the process and wait for crash.

Comment: gdb for windows seems pretty hard to get running... but i will see..

Comment: no it's not: run gdb, get pid, attach pid, run process

Comment: When I run gdb python test.py in cmd, I got the following: 'Reading symbols from C:\Python27\python.exe...(no debugging symbols found)...done. "path/test.py" is not a core dump:File format not recognized'